# code working but when clicked first time, it does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this jquery code

its not working as expected

```
$(document).on('submit','#frmNotification',function(e) {
    var results = checkForm(this);
    if (results) {
        $('#frmNotification').validate({
            submitHandler: function(form){
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        type: "info",
                        text: response,
                        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-confirm mt-2"
                    });
                }            
            });     
        }
        }); 
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

it only works on the second click, but not on first click,

`frmNotification` is the formname

buttonname is `btnSubmit`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? What does `checkForm` contain?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're attaching the actual submit listener after the first submit...

Try this:

```js
$('#frmNotification').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var results = checkForm(form);
        if (results) {
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        type: "info",
                        text: response,
                        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-confirm mt-2"
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```